# Return tag of the label when it it tapped

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, xcode4.5, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have 5 labels in my view, respectively tagged 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. I have enabled *user interaction* on them, and added a tap gesture.

Now what I want is to get the tag of the label being touched.

I am doing something like this:

```
tapGesture=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureSelector)];

tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1.0;     

- (void)tapGestureSelector :(id)sender
{
    // I need the tag to perform different tasks.
    // So that I would like to get the touched label's tag here.    
}
```

If I am not clear in my question please ask me.

Thanks in anticipation for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution in this way and it worked for me very fine. I hope that it will also help you. It is very simple and short.

**We can get the Tag of the label by adding this function into our .m file.**

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
    UILabel *label=(UILabel *)touch.view;

    NSLog(@"Label that is tapped has tag %d",label.tag);
}
```

Thanks again for all of your very nice suggestions and answers. I hope I will always get good answers of my all questions from SO in future. Thanks to all again.

Comment: Then what is the use of tapgesture ? You don't need to add gesture to UIlabel then.

Comment: Yes ! Actually, I have not tested this functionality without adding the gesture to our label and any object, but YES to your answer after testing I can conclude that with **tochesBegan** function we don't need to add gesture of our label.

Thanks Midhun MP to clearify me. Thanks a lot. Have a nice day.

Comment: @MidhunMP :: Please vote up my answer as I have updated it. Thanks buddy in anticipation.

Comment: ok, done that. But remember the touches began will work for all touches on the view not only for label means if you touch on the view, then also it'll work

Comment: @MidhunMP: Yes! It is working for all the objects on the View.and UIView is also an object, so it will work for view it too.

Comment: is that your requirement ? According to your question this is not a good question. Anyway thanks for your comment :) have a good day

Comment: @MidhunMP :: This was not my actually requirement, mine was just to get the tags of the labels, but doing with this, if I will have to get tags of any other object, I will get easily. 

Thank a lot buddy, all of you guys helped me a lot. Have a nice day. Good bye.

Answer (score 1):

For accessing the tag of `UILabel` you need to use the following code in your `tapGestureSelector` method.

```
- (void)tapGestureSelector :(id)sender
    {
        UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
        int labelTag = gesture.view.tag;
        NSlog(@"Clicked label %d", labelTag);

        switch(labelTag)
        {
           case 1:
                 NSlog(@"Clicked on label 1");
                 break;
           case 2:
                 NSlog(@"Clicked on label 2");
                 break;

           //so on
        }
    }
```

Comment: gesture.view is the view gesture added to not the view tapped.

Comment: @sunkehappy: gesture is added to UILabel, so if we tapped on the label, the `tapGestureSelector` will work, then the gesture.view will give the UILabel. label.tag will give the tag of label. Read the question carefully before downvoting.

Comment: Are you sure gesture is added to UILabel? There five UILable, will you add five UITapGestureRecognizer? One for each UILabel? While I think add a UITapGestureRecognizer to self will be a better idea.

Comment: @sunkehappy: Please read this line from his question **I have 5 labels in my view tags 1,2,3,4,5 respectively. I have enabled the user interaction mode on then and also applied the Tap gesture.**

Comment: @sunkehappy: then what is the need of tapgesture ? When you touch on the view the `touchesBegan` delegate will automatically work, then no need to add tapgesture in it.

Comment: @sunkehappy: Adding tap gesture for each label is much easier way to find the tapped Label than checking it using `CGPoint tapPoint = [tapGesture locationInView:self.view]` `CGRectContainsPoint(self.oneLabel.frame, tapPoint)` If there are 100 UILabels will you add 100 if conditions ? or just add tap gestures on them ?

Comment: Although very strange, I'll vote you back. Let the questioner decide.

Comment: @sunkehappy: ok, let him decide :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19385/discussion-between-sunkehappy-and-midhun-mp)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I've added `oneLabel` and `twoLabel` as subview to `self.view`. Then I think there is no need to get the tag.

```
CGPoint tapPoint = [tapGesture locationInView:self.view];

if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.oneLabel.frame, tapPoint)) {
    NSLog(@"tapped one label");
} else if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.twoLabel.frame, tapPoint)) {
    NSLog(@"tapped two label");
}
```