# Sending argument with a Selector inside an initWithTarget call

Tags: objective-c, syntax, arguments, selector

I'm trying to trim the following code down to a single method. At present, eight identical methods are used to process a tap on eight `UIButton` instances. Ideally, I'd just like to pass the `UIButton` as an argument into the `@selector` so I can avoid needing eight identical methods. I'm struggling with the syntax of passing an argument to a selector. I'd want a `handleTap: onButton:` method, if possible. At present, there are eight methods (`handleTap1` through `handleTap8`) which do an identical operation, on buttons 1 through 8.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(handleTap1:)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(handleTap2:)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap3 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(handleTap3:)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap4 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(handleTap4:)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap5 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(handleTap5:)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap6 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(handleTap6:)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap7 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(handleTap7:)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap8 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(handleTap8:)];
[let1Button addGestureRecognizer: tap1];
[let2Button addGestureRecognizer: tap2];
[let3Button addGestureRecognizer: tap3];
[let4Button addGestureRecognizer: tap4];
[let5Button addGestureRecognizer: tap5];
[let6Button addGestureRecognizer: tap6];
[let7Button addGestureRecognizer: tap7];
[let8Button addGestureRecognizer: tap8];
```

Here's an example of one of the methods, obviously I'd like to replace `let1Button` with a passed-in argument to represent any button.

```
- (void) handleTap1: (UITapGestureRecognizer *) recognizer
{
    [_box setText: [_box.text stringByAppendingString: [let1Button titleForState: UIControlStateNormal]]];
    [let1Button setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [let1Button setTitleColor: [UIColor blackColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Comment: Why are you manually adding gesture recognisers to buttons? They already have them, and will send events accordingly.

Comment: I'm using buttons which can be both dragged and tapped, and without the tap gesture, it got very confused over whether the touch up inside coming off a drag constituted a click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[UIView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)(`UIButton` is a subclass of `UIView`) has a property `view`. It is the view the gesture recognizer is attached to

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(handleTap:)];
[let1Button addGestureRecognizer: tap1];

- (void) handleTap: (UITapGestureRecognizer *) recognizer
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)recognizer.view;
    [_box setText: [_box.text stringByAppendingString: [UIButton titleForState: UIControlStateNormal]]];
    [UIButton  setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [UIButton setTitleColor: [UIColor blackColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Comment: Follow-up: if I add the same recognizer to multiple buttons, it only attaches to the last one I did. Can you not attach a single gesture recognizer to multiple buttons?

Comment: A gesture recogniser can only belong to a single view.

Comment: One gesture recognizer can only be attached to one view. Check my this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/a/13306076/1548523 on how to check which view has been tapped.

Answer (score 1):

The gesture recognizer has a property view. You can check that to figure out on which button the gesture was performed.

Comment: Which property can I use? `recognizer` seems to have its own properties, none of which I can set from a UIButton. Am I missing something?

Comment: It has a property "view". A UIButton is a subclass of UIView. Therefore the "view" property should hold in your case the UIButton to which you have added the recognizer.

Answer (score 1):

The gesture recognizer ist handed over as parameter to the action. 
Within the action method you can access the view.

```
UIView myView = recognizer.view
if (myView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class])
{
   ...
}
```